# How shiro verified in different ways according to the URL prefix

Tags: java, shiro

```
 <Filter>
            <Filter-name> shiroFilter </ filter-name>
            <Filter-class> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy </ filter-class>
            <Init-param>
                <Param-name> targetFilterLifecycle </ param-name>
                <Param-value> true </ param-value>
            </ Init-param>
        </ Filter>
            <Filter-mapping>
                <Filter-name> shiroFilter </ filter-name>
                <Url-pattern> / admin / * </ url-pattern>
            </ Filter-mapping>
    
        <Filter>
        <Filter-name> menberShiroFilter </ filter-name>
            <Filter-class> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy </ filter-class>
            <Init-param>
                <Param-name> targetFilterLifecycle </ param-name>
                <Param-value> true </ param-value>
            </ Init-param>
        </ Filter>
            <Filter-mapping>
                <Filter-name> menberShiroFilter </ filter-name>
                <Url-pattern> / menber / * </ url-pattern>
            </ Filter-mapping>
```

When shiro and web integration is configured in web.xml

The question now is: When in the same view, through access to the admin prefixed url successful login, jump to the home page, such as http: // localhost: 8080 / admin / index.do, then enter this browser window http: // localhost: 8080 / menber / index.do, the time to menber as it can directly access the URL prefix, and does not need to log in now demand is: If menber is not logged in URL prefix must be logged, how can we achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow the question completely, you may want to take a look at this doc: http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-WebINIconfiguration

Instead of defining the filter mapping twice, you could filter everything '/*'. and then configure your access requirements via the shiro.ini (or a spring bean)

    `[urls]
    /index.html = anon
    /user/create = anon
    /user/** = authc
    /admin/** = authc, roles[administrator]
    /remoting/rpc/** = authc, perms["remote:invoke"]`

This was taken from an existing example, in this case `index.html` and `/user/create` are available to an anonymous user, `/user/**` just requires a logged in user. `/admin/**` requires a logged in user with the `administrator` permission.  And finally  `/remoting/rpc/**` requires a logged in user with the permission `remote:invoke`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a question: http: // localhost: 8080 / admin / login.jsp login is successful, in the same browser and enter http: // localhost: 8080 / menber / index, if not menber login, you should jump to http: // localhost: 8080 / menber / login.jsp login page. According to your approach, clearly can not be achieved ah, because they are a common subject, I demand that this how? Thank you. .